# pass array in query params Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, http-get, angular-httpclient, query-string

How form a URL with array of query params with Angular HttpClient

**input**
`ids: string[] = ["1","2","3"]`

**output**
`eg: https://localhost:8080/cinemas?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3`

Answer (score 2):

Simply use appendAll() and pass there {"param": Array}

```
let queryParams = new HttpParams();

queryParams = queryParams.appendAll({'ids': ids});

return this.http.get(backendUrl + '/cinemas?' + queryParams.toString());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
  
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  url = https://localhost:8080/cinemas

  public getCinemas(ids: string[]) {
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    for (let k = 0; k < ids.length; k++) {
      queryParams = queryParams.append('ids', ids[k]);
    }
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + `?${queryParams.toString()}`);
  }
```

Comment: I suppose the above is just a typo and you are using the correct variable, ie `ids[k]` instead of `relationIds[k]`?