# sending array as a query param in angular post request

Tags: angular

I have the following angular post request :

```js
this._http.post(
        RESOURCE_URL, // my query URL
        {
          params : {
            houses: ids
          }
        }
      );
```

the variable `ids` is an array of numbers that I send to the back end, with `ids = [1,2]` for instance.
my issue is, as I send my request, it is sent as the following `RESOURCE_URL?houses=1&houses=2`, which is not what I want.

I'm trying to have it more like this : `RESOURCE_URL?houses=[1,2]`.

Now one may suggest why I don't just pass it on to the request body. Problem is, for prject-specific reasons, I cannot. Too much work would be required and I do not have power to decide whether I should dive into it or not.

is there anyway this can be done ? because haveing looked at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217941/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string-in-httpclient) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478890/pass-array-in-query-params-angular-httpclient), and it seems like it's just not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, it's just not the way Angular does this. So, just do it manually.

```js
this._http.post('my_url', {
  params: {
    houses: `[${ids.join(',')}]`
  }
})
```